# marshalling multidimensional list using JAXB

Tags: multidimensional-array, jaxb

I'm trying to write to XML an object that has fields referencing multidimensional lists, but it doesn't work, in the XML file I see the field names but no values

this is my object:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
public class DataHolder {

// some fields here

private List<ArrayList <Integer>> status = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

private List<ArrayList <Double>> balance = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

private List<ArrayList<String>> date = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

}
```

I know I can wrap inner lists and have something like List`<Object`>
but I'd have to change a lot of supporting code for this, is there another option?

Comment: Please add a sample XML you'd like to have. And yes, you can probably achieve this with an `@XmlAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using lists of wrapped lists, thanks.